# Firebase database ordering function startAt(boolean)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

What does Firebase database `startAt(boolean)` do?

[Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#startAt(boolean)) says:

> Create a query constrained to only return child nodes with a value
>   greater than or equal to the given value, using the given orderBy
>   directive or priority as default.

How can boolean be greater than another boolean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not a value is greater than another is defined by the ordering method. The method that Firebase uses is [explained in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#data-order):

> When using `orderByChild()`, data that contains the specified child key is ordered as follows:
>
> 1. Children with a `null` value for the specified child key come first.
> 2. Children with a value of `false` for the specified child key come next. If multiple children have a value of `false`, they are sorted lexicographically by key.
> 3. Children with a value of `true` for the specified child key come next. If multiple children have a value of `true`, they are sorted lexicographically by key.
> 4. Children with a numeric value come next, sorted in ascending order. If multiple children have the same numerical value for the specified child node, they are sorted by key.
> 5. Strings come after numbers and are sorted lexicographically in ascending order. If multiple children have the same value for the specified child node, they are ordered lexicographically by key.
> 6. Objects come last and are sorted lexicographically by key in ascending order.

So as far as Firebase's ordering is concerned, `true` is greater than `false`.

Comment: Oh, that's it. so if I want to filter all nodes that have foo child I would do reference.orderByChild("foo").startAt(false). Isn't there a more readable way  to do it?

Comment: That's just the way it works, as Firebase queries are range-based. If you have some constraints on the values you are storing in `foo`, you could get something more readable. For example, if you are storing positive integers, `startAt(0)` would be more readable. And if you are storing strings `startAt("")` might work (I've not tried it). It depends upon the data.